# Creating an intermediate branch with git

Tags: git

I have a git repository that has tags for when a release is made. For example, I have tags 3.3.10, 4.0.3, 4.1.5, etc.

Something came up where 4.0.3 needs to be modified with a 4.0.4 release. If I checkout the 4.0.3 tag, it tells me that HEAD is detached. So now when I make changes, how would I commit them? Would the following be the proper flow?

- Clone the repo: `git clone <project>`
- Checkout the tag: `git checkout 4.0.3`
- Make any necessary changes to the code
- Create a new branch from the current code: `git checkout -b dev_4.0.4`
- Create my tag: `git tag -a 4.0.4`
- Push the new tag to remote: `git push origin 4.0.4`
- At this point I can delete the dev branch: `git branch -d dev_4.0.4`

Does this look right? I'm essentially just wanting to tag a new version of code. I did some searching and read some topics about HEAD, but I'd like to make sure I have a full grasp on what it is I'm about to do.

Comment: I would swap steps 3 and 4. Once you checkout at tag 4.0.3, create a new branch, make changes, commit, and once you are done, create a new tag, push to remote and delete the branch.

Comment: I agree with @gustavovelascoh and potentially you'll have to merge your change in the upstream(s)

Comment: @AntoineWils, the merge could or not be merged, depending on if the new branch (4.0.4) is like a support branch for custom developments (support to old customer, new feature required for a previous version). In this case, I guess it shouldn't be merged as it is not desired to affect newer releases. In the case of a security update or something that affects all version, the changes should be merged.

Comment: @gustavovelascoh I fully agree. It is why I document it as "potentially" to be merged. I only want to highlight that is a question that you have to ask your self in the fow

Comment: @gustavovelascoh perfect, thank you for confirming and for the suggestion. If you put that as an answer I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would swap steps 3 and 4. Once you checkout at tag 4.0.3, create a new branch, make changes, commit, and once you are done, create a new tag, push to remote and delete the branch.

As discussed with @AntoineWils, the branch could or not be merged, depending on if the new branch (4.0.4) is like a support branch for custom developments (support to an old customer or new feature required for a previous version). In this case, I guess it shouldn't be merged as it is not desired to affect newer releases.

In the case of a security update or something that affects all versions, the changes should be merged.

Comment: This answer is unclear. There are no "steps 3" or "4", just bullet points. What if the Q has been edited? The steps should be laid out by the answer, not as a puzzle to solve between the two.